# Aggregation links and RSTP

Tags: switch, spanning-tree, redundancy

If aggregation links are used for redundancy to ensure the devices stay active if a link fails, does RSTP need to be configured due to there being 2 links?

Comment: Link aggregation fools STP into thinking the multiple interfaces are a single, aggregated interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSTP/RSTP isn't required when all multiple links are aggregated.

However, you'd likely want to activate and configure STP anyway as it protects your network in case an accidental loop is created. Without STP, the loop causes a broadcast storm, bringing down your network. Note that xSTP must be active on the device creating the loop, so you need to configure it an *all* switches.

As Ron's pointed out, STP treats a LAG trunk as a single, logical interface. Accordingly, STP doesn't interfere with aggregation and there's no need to turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.  You can use 802.3ad or other LAG technologies without being forced to use xSTP.

Comment: The question is precisely about the usefulness of xSTP when using Link Aggregation..